# Window titles often remain displayed after closing a window or minimizing it

Tags: 14.04, unity, bug-reporting, titlebar

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system. Whenever I minimize a window or close it , the title bar of the window still remains there. Like if I minimize or close Firefox, the title bar of firefox is still there on a different app. When I click on the screen then the title bar goes of. The image shows the problem .[[Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQzkB.png)

The Image shows that when I minimized firefox, the firefox title bar still appeared on my terminal. Now when I click on terminal, then I get the terminal titlebar.

How can I fix this?
Thankyou